# Custom type sort in C++ compared with Java generics

Tags: java, c++, templates, generics

The problem is how to implement custom sorting algorithm that works for any type of data (precise sorting algorithm is irrelevant here). In Java, you create a generic container, e.g. `List<T>`, where `T` needs to implement Comparable interface. That ensures that any two elements of type `T` can be compared using `compareTo` method and, basing on it, you may apply total order to elements of a list.

Java has generics and C++ has templates. Anyway, C++ doesn't use interfaces at all (only abstract classes). What is the recommended, good-design way, to implement custom-type sort in C++? For example, I've got a `Person` class which I want to sort by age field (or whatever). How shall I do this?

Comment: Study the `sort` function in the standard library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is expectation that if the type has an ordering, it can be compared using `<` operator. So for example if you want to sort a class/struct using `std::sort`, you would write something like this:

```
struct foo{
    int x, y;
};

inline bool operator< (const foo& lhs, const foo& rhs){ /* do actual comparison */ }
```

and now the `std::sort(begin(vec), end(vec)` form of `std::sort` works.
Of course, there is another way to declare the `<` operator for structs/classes:

```
struct foo{
    int x, y;
    bool operator<(const foo& rhs){
    /* do comparison */
    } 
};
```

Otherwise you can also just take comparison function as an argument of the sort function, like this:

```
 std::sort(begin(vec), end(vec), [](const foo& lhs, const foo& rhs) {
    /* do the actual comparison */   
 });
```

*(The possibly weird looking thing as third argument is a lambda function)*

---edit---
Hopefully I fixed all the stupid mistakes like forgetting semi-colons where needed. I blame being away from computer for the last week. :-)

Comment: that's exactly what I was thinking of. Thanks for the code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an stl container such as vector and then use the stl sort algorithm, which accepts a compare function which can do anything you want.